# Getting a textbox value to create a link in the same page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to create a link with the following `href` attribute:

```
app\process?val=12000
```

but the value for the `val` parameter (in this case `12000`) must come from the value of a textbox on the page.

I know that I can use `$(#textbox).value()` to get the value, but I need to change the link when the value changes.

Comment: Did you find an acceptable solution to your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yWTfE/2/)** of something you could try.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text"></input>
<button type="button" id="button">Get Link</button>
<br/>
<a href="#">Test Link</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    param = $("#text").val();
    alert("www.example.com\apps?val=" + param);
    $("a").attr("href", "www.example.com\apps?val=" + param);
});​
```

In the OP you have `$(#textbox).value()`, but there are a few things wrong with this. First the selector needs to be wrapped in quotes like `$("#textbox")` where textbox is the ID of the element. Also, `.value()` is not a function in jQuery and is actually `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="link">this is a link </a>


$('#textbox').change(function(){
    $('#link').attr('href', 'app\process?val=' + this.value);
});
```